# Creating multiple listview dynamically from json data

Tags: android, json, listview, android-listview

I need to parse a `JSON` and with the help of that `JSON` I need to make dynamic listviews (it can be 2 or 3 or any).

```
[
  {
    "Monday, Feb 16": [
      {
        "Time": "19-02-2015 12:00:00",
        "Image": "India.png",
        "Currency": "  INR",
        "Event": "WPI Food (YoY) (Jan)",
        "Actual": "8.00%",
        "Forcast": "",
        "Previous": "5.20%"
      },
      {
        "Time": "19-02-2015 12:00:00",
        "Image": "India.png",
        "Currency": "  INR",
        "Event": "WPI Fuel (YoY) (Jan)",
        "Actual": "-10.69%",
        "Forcast": "",
        "Previous": "-7.80%"
      },
      {
        "Time": "19-02-2015 12:00:00",
        "Image": "India.png",
        "Currency": "  INR",
        "Event": "WPI Inflation (YoY) (Jan)",
        "Actual": "-0.39%",
        "Forcast": "0.41%",
        "Previous": "0.11%"
      },
      {
        "Time": "19-02-2015 12:00:00",
        "Image": "India.png",
        "Currency": "  INR",
        "Event": "WPI Manufacturing Inflation (YoY) (Jan)",
        "Actual": "1.05%",
        "Forcast": "",
        "Previous": "1.57%"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Wednesday, Feb 18": [
      {
        "Time": "19-02-2015 17:00:00",
        "Image": "India.png",
        "Currency": "  INR",
        "Event": "M3 Money Supply (2wk)",
        "Actual": "11.40%",
        "Forcast": "",
        "Previous": "11.20%"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Friday, Feb 20": [
      {
        "Time": "19-02-2015 17:00:00",
        "Image": "India.png",
        "Currency": "  INR",
        "Event": "Bank Loan Growth (2wk)",
        "Actual": "",
        "Forcast": "",
        "Previous": "10.70%"
      },
      {
        "Time": "19-02-2015 17:00:00",
        "Image": "India.png",
        "Currency": "  INR",
        "Event": "Deposit Growth (2wk)",
        "Actual": "",
        "Forcast": "",
        "Previous": "11.60%"
      },
      {
        "Time": "19-02-2015 17:00:00",
        "Image": "India.png",
        "Currency": "  INR",
        "Event": "FX Reserves, USD",
        "Actual": "",
        "Forcast": "",
        "Previous": "330.21B"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Here "Monday,Feb 16" "Wednesday, Feb 18" "Friday, Feb 20" should be 3 headings and shows we need to make 3 listviews and others are items of listview.

I parsed the json getting all keys and items. Now how can i make listviews dynamically.

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(sResponse);
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject jObj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
    Iterator<?> keys = jObj.keys();

    // while (keys.hasNext()) {
    String key = (String) keys.next();
    JSONArray jArr = jObj.getJSONArray(key);
    Log.e("Key", "Key :-" + key);
    for (int i1 = 0; i1 < jArr.length(); i1++) {

        JSONObject jsO = jArr.getJSONObject(i1);
        Log.e("Event", jsO.getString("Event"));
    }
```

Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: Make a pojo class with the string fields (name same as in Json) and then make an arraylist of that pojo type. Now populate the arraylist with the json data in that for loop of yours.

Comment: I need to made listviews it can  be 3 or 4 like in this case its 3, example :- Header (Feb 16) and thn items of that< 2nd header(Feb 18) and then items of that < 3rd (Feb 20) header and then items

Comment: I can populate and all stuff but issue is making multiple listviews

Comment: Yes Tushar i need seprate listviews for separate date.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71241/discussion-between-tushar-and-rohit).

Comment: Consider an Expandable List View ?